# Почему некорректно работает уникальный составной индекс в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица с уникальным составным индексом из 2 полей, вот запрос для её создания:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq` (`field1`,`field2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Никак не пойму, почему я могу добавлять одинаковые записи при условии, что поле field1 равен NULL. Вот пример наполнения таблицы:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (3, 1, 2, 1),
    (4, NULL, 1, 1),
    (5, NULL, 1, 1),
    (6, NULL, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято [отсюда](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> For all engines, a UNIQUE index allows multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

Т.е., по сути, разрешив вставлять в один из столбцов значения NULL вы тем самым сами сломали UNIQUE индекс.

Comment: Формально говоря, уникальность-то при этом сохраняется, поскольку сравнение двух NULLов дает ложь.

Comment: Хм, действительно. Странный MySQL. Как я понял этого не избежать и просто смириться?

Comment: @ИванТоргов все зависит от того, что нужно. По вашему примеру это не ясно. Либо делайте поле не null, либо, если поля более корректные, а не field1/field2/field3, то, возможно, вам нужна другая таблица со связью её и данной таблицей через `foreign key`

Comment: @Yaant `SELECT NULL != NULL` дает `null`......`SELECT NULL = NULL` дает `null` ...... так что непонятно о какой целостности вы говорите

Comment: Избежать этого можно одним способом. Сделать все поля индекса NOT NULL. Поскольку Вы их, согласно примеру, заполняете значениями явно, выберите некоторое формально невозможное значение (на показанных данных сойдёт, например, MAXUINT = 4294967295), и используйте его вместо NULL. К сожалению, все запросы, которые используют присвоение полю значения NULL явно, придётся переписывать...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Немного неточно выразился. Суть в том, что подходя формально, нельзя сказать, что два NULL'а равны друг другу, и соответственно, сколько бы ни было в столбце NULL'ов, двух равных значений там все равно не будет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, образно говоря, моя таблица имеет следующие поля: id, date, entity1_id, entity2_id, stat. В ней entity1_id и entity2_id связаны с другими таблицами через foreign key, stat - какая либо статистика. Уникальный индекс на 3 поля - date + entity1_id + entity2_id. При этом entity2 является уточнением, грубо говоря, и иногда может отсутствовать. Следовательно, Akina, ваш способ не очень подходит, ибо придется еще создавать записи в таблице entity2.